# Getting all active connections in ActionCable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I'm building a chat between two users. When an user sends a message, I need the app to identify if the receiver of the message is on the chat; if not, the app should notify the receiver.

My situation on backend is: every user has one connection and the connection is subscribed to the channel of the chat the user is on.

What I'm doing to identify if the receiver is same chat is get all connections whose user is the receiver and then I check if channel is on the identifiers of the subscritions of these connections.

I'm using `ActionCable.server.connections` to get connections.

The issue here is: this method will, sometimes, return a different array of connections for every user, so my solution won't work (if it returns the same array, the code works).

How do I get all the connections?
Or maybe how can I know an user is a channel or not?
I want to notify users properly. It doesn't matter if I will have to change the whole logic.

Comment: I'm not sure this information is readily available as there may be many server processes that are handling different client connections, so no one process knows about all connections. You may need to track this using a connection table with a timeout, like a Redis key with a TTL.